# How to make drop-zone clickable in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

In my web form application, I have used a drop-zone where users will drop files to upload them. At the movement, when I drop a file on the drop-zone, it works fine and I can easily upload that file by clicking the button located down the drop-zone.

However, I want to open the upload file dialog when someone will click on the drop-zone. How can I make the drop-zone clickable so that upload file dialog is shown where I can choose the file to upload. I have searched different techniques but nothing works fine. Is there any way that can help me achieve my goal easily?

My drop-zone HTML is here.

```
<div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">
 <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
</div>
```

I am looking to achieve this goal with the following jQuery code in document.ready.

```
              var userEmail = $("#hdnFolderPath").val();
              var uploadButton = document.querySelector("#upload");

              Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

              $("#dZUpload").dropzone({
                  url: "/ReceiptStorage/Handlers/FileHandler.ashx",
                  params: {
                      DestinationPath: userEmail
                  },
                  autoProcessQueue: false,
                  addRemoveLinks: true,

                  init: function () {
                      var uploadButton = document.querySelector("#upload");
                      var dZUpload = this; //closure

                      dZUpload.on("complete", function (file, response) {
                          if (file.status === 'success') {
                              dZUpload.removeFile(file);
                              LoadFiles($("#hdnFolderPath").val());
                          }
                      });
                      dZUpload.on('error', function (file, response) { 
                      });
                      uploadButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
                          if (dZUpload.files.length > 0)
                              dZUpload.processQueue();
                      });
                  }    
              });
```

Comment: @Reza Aghaei ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the **JQuery** that is used as the template for every file dropped:

```
var previewNode = document.querySelector("#template");
previewNode.id = "";
var previewTemplate = previewNode.parentNode.innerHTML;
previewNode.parentNode.removeChild(previewNode);

var myDropzone = new Dropzone(document.body, { // Make the whole body a dropzone
  url: "/target-url", // Set the url
  thumbnailWidth: 80,
  thumbnailHeight: 80,
  parallelUploads: 20,
  previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
  autoQueue: false, // Make sure the files aren't queued until manually added
  previewsContainer: "#previews", // Define the container to display the previews
  clickable: ".fileinput-button" // Define the element that should be used as click trigger to select files.
});

myDropzone.on("addedfile", function(file) {
  // Hookup the start button
  file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").onclick = function() { myDropzone.enqueueFile(file); };
});

// Update the total progress bar
myDropzone.on("totaluploadprogress", function(progress) {
  document.querySelector("#total-progress .progress-bar").style.width = progress + "%";
});

myDropzone.on("sending", function(file) {
  // Show the total progress bar when upload starts
  document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "1";
  // And disable the start button
  file.previewElement.querySelector(".start").setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
});

// Hide the total progress bar when nothing's uploading anymore
myDropzone.on("queuecomplete", function(progress) {
  document.querySelector("#total-progress").style.opacity = "0";
});

// Setup the buttons for all transfers
// The "add files" button doesn't need to be setup because the config
// `clickable` has already been specified.
document.querySelector("#actions .start").onclick = function() {
  myDropzone.enqueueFiles(myDropzone.getFilesWithStatus(Dropzone.ADDED));
};
document.querySelector("#actions .cancel").onclick = function() {
  myDropzone.removeAllFiles(true);
};
```